# Error importing geotiff file with rgdal

Tags: r, gis

I am trying to read in [this ASTER/GDEM geotiff file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1791181/ASTGTM2_N22E086_dem_shade_color.tif) using readGDAL{rgdal}. I know that GDAL on its own can read the file just fine, since `gdalinfo /path/file.tif` gives the following output:

```
Size is 3601, 3601
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (85.999861111111116,23.000138888888888)
Pixel Size = (0.000277777777778,-0.000277777777778)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  85.9998611,  23.0001389) ( 85d59'59.50"E, 23d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Left  (  85.9998611,  21.9998611) ( 85d59'59.50"E, 21d59'59.50"N)
Upper Right (  87.0001389,  23.0001389) ( 87d 0' 0.50"E, 23d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Right (  87.0001389,  21.9998611) ( 87d 0' 0.50"E, 21d59'59.50"N)
Center      (  86.5000000,  22.5000000) ( 86d30' 0.00"E, 22d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=3601x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=3601x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=3601x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

But when I try to import the file into R using the following code:

```
a = readGDAL(system.file("/path/file.tif", package="rgdal")[1])
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in readGDAL(system.file("/path/file.tif",  : 
  empty file name
```

I have tried with other geotiff files, and I get the same error message. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of importing GTiff files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear, your file name is incorrect.

You don't need `system.file`, that is to "Find Names of R System Files" (see `?system.file`).

Try using the path to your file:

```
 a = readGDAL("/path/file.tif")
```

You can check it exists with

```
file.exists("/path/file.tif")
```

Comment: I see. I was just following the rgdal documentation. Good to know. Thanks, mdsumner.